# Printing elements of a variable with type class 'list' in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested, aruco

I have a variable with a shape of [1, 1, 4, 2]. The variable basically has the data (x and y coordinates) corresponding to getting 4 corners of a square (using ArUco markers). The information comes in this form (example on printing out the variable) -

```
[array([[[437., 387.],
        [367., 382.],
        [372., 310.],
        [439., 316.]]], dtype=float32)]
```

How can I extract the x and y coordinates and save it in a variable? Eg. how can I store a = 437 & b = 387, for instance?

I tried converting it to a numpy array but again the same problem. I get the output as a nested array inside a nested array inside a nested array ([[[[]]]]]) -

```
[[[[439. 415.]
   [365. 416.]
   [362. 342.]
   [433. 340.]]]]
```

Adding my code here. This code helps get center Aruco Marker identification in real time -

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, PIL, os
from cv2 import aruco

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_4X4_250)
    parameters =  aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
    corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)
    frame_markers = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame.copy(), corners, ids)

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame_markers)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: You can use `numpy.squeeze` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html

Comment: What is `array`? `print(type(array))`

Comment: @tdelaney - array is not a variable here. So, print(type(array)) returns nothing (Error).

Comment: We can't answer this question without knowing your data. This isn't a runnable program so I need to guess. Is that python code where you make a 1 element list  by calling something called `array`? Did you print some object and this is its string equivalent? I was trying to figure out what your data structure is.

Comment: @tdelaney added code.